# How to correct "Error : Command errored out with exit statut 1"

Tags: python, conda

I am working on Conda and am trying to word tokenize and lemmatize a french corpus of text. Being a beginner, I found on git a lemmatizer I was able to install (via pip10.1 and git) and a tokenizer I am not able to install.

I tried to install it using pip10.1
`(base) C:\Users\Bianca>pip install git+https://github.com/boudinfl/kea`
However, I have the resulting code :

```
  Collecting git+https://github.com/boudinfl/kea
  Cloning https://github.com/boudinfl/kea to c:\users\bianca\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-imn5lund
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/boudinfl/kea 'C:\Users\Bianca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-imn5lund'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Bianca\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bianca\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-imn5lund\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bianca\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-imn5lund\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Bianca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-imn5lund\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Bianca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-imn5lund\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Bianca\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Bianca\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-imn5lund\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I use Python3.7. How can I fix it?

Thanks! 
Bianca

Comment: Hi Bianca, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Happy coding!

Comment: This repository does not offer an installable python package, so you cannot install it with pip. You might be able to make it work by cloning the repository and setting `PYTHONPATH` variable to make it importable. Note that the code is quite old and may or may not work with python3.

Comment: Thanks for the help : I tried on Spacy instead which was able to partially fix it.